# KVM + Xenial Server. libvirt-bin won't configure

Tags: server, virtualization, 16.04, kvm-virtualization, aptitude

I just (foolishly) completed the upgrade from 14.04.4 to 16.04. Apparently there's a bug due to the introduction of systemd that breaks libvirt... or I've broken aptitude. Is there a workaround or fix for this? Should I go back to 14.04?

```
root@KVM0:~# apt-get install libvirt-bin
Reading package 
lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
libvirt-bin is already the newest version (1.3.1-1ubuntu10).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up libvirt-bin (1.3.1-1ubuntu10) ...
Job for libvirt-bin.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status libvirt-bin.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript libvirt-bin, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package libvirt-bin (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libvirt-bin
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: The problem seems to be described in this bug:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libvirt/+bug/1594902

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to be caused by apparmor as you will find something similar to this in your syslog:

> kernel: [ 2386.130467] audit: type=1400 audit(1461767119.644:89): apparmor="DENIED" operation="create" profile="/usr/sbin/libvirtd" pid=21368 comm="libvirtd" family="netlink" sock_type="raw" protocol=0 requested_mask="create" denied_mask="create"

Until the bug is fixed, one insecure workaround is to temporarily disable apparmor for the installation:

```
sudo systemctl stop apparmor.service
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo systemctl start apparmor.service
```

Answer (score 1):

Please don't uncomment this in `/etc/libvirt/libvirtd.conf`:

```
# You need to uncomment this line
log_outputs="3:syslog:libvirtd"
```

Leave it as the default like:

```
# You need to uncomment this line
#log_outputs="3:syslog:libvirtd"
```

It was referred to in the official libvirt wiki: http://wiki.libvirt.org/page/The_daemon_cannot_be_started, but it doesn't help at all.

The best option is to first run:

```
sudo systemctl stop apparmor.service
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo systemctl start apparmor.service
```

Then you can try:

```
systemctl status libvirt-bin.service
```

The output of which should be something like this:

```
libvirt-bin.service - Virtualization daemon

Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/libvirt-bin.service; enabled; vendor prese

Active: active (running) since Fr 2016-08-19 14:02:04 EST; 43s ago
Docs: man:libvirtd(8)
       http://libvirt.org

Main PID: 8620 (libvirtd)
CGroup: /system.slice/libvirt-bin.service
       ├─8620 /usr/sbin/libvirtd
       ├─9013 /usr/sbin/dnsmasq --conf-file=/var/lib/libvirt/dnsmasq/default.
       └─9014 /usr/sbin/dnsmasq --conf-file=/var/lib/libvirt/dnsmasq/default.
```

Comment: I get that output but after that there is a line in red: `libvirtd[1008]: End of file while reading data: Input/output error`

Answer (score 0):

I had simillar problem with apt dist-upgrade. I fix it by stoping libvirt-bin service and killing all running libvirt processes.